# How do I get the gradient and asset image to work together?

Tags: flutter, dart, gradient

The only error that I get is "the named parameter 'body' isn't defined."
... how do I fix that?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter, 
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter, 
            colors: [const Color(0xFF50658C), const Color(0xFF2D4067)]
       ),
     ),
    ),
          body: Center(
            child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/space.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your issue in a clear way. Code is currently edited and well formated... can you edit the question to explain your problem properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image should go inside the decoration of the container for the gradient to be applied. When you assign the image to the container's child, it will appear on top of all the decorations.
You would want your container to look like this.

```
           Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [const Color(0xFF50658C), const Color(0xFF2D4067)]
                ),
                image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/space.png'))
              ),
            )
```